# JQuery Set Option in Opt Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out how to set an option inside of a optgroup using JQuery and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a hidden field on the page that contains the following value 4-2014. On ready I would like to read the hidden value and set the selected option.

html:

```
<select name="dropdownlist" id="dropdownlist">
<option value="All">All</option>
<optgroup label="2013" id="2013">
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="2014" id="2014">
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</optgroup>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 //set the dropdown selected item.
 var varDropdownvalue = $("input[id$=Dropdownvalue]").val();
 var monthyear = varDropdownvalue.split('-');
 $('#dropdownlist #'+monthyear[1]+' option[value='+monthyear[0]+']').prop("selected", true);
      $('#dropdownlist').change(function () {      
          //get the optgroup label and value of selected option.
          var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
          var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  alert(value+'-'+label);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netmonster/LPAFD/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#dropdownlist').val(monthyear[0]).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPAFD/1/

Comment: That's great stuff, simple.

Answer (score 0):

Field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_select" value="4-2014" />
```

JS:

```
var hidden = $("#hidden_select").val().split("-");
var month = hidden[0];
var year = hidden[1];
var list = $("#dropdownlist");
var theOption = list.find('optgroup#'+year+' option[value="'+month+'"]').val();
list.val(theOption).change();
```